# WSD seems to be crashing my print spooler. How do I get around it?

Tags: windows-10, network-printer, print-spooler

Earlier this month I asked about not being able to add a printer on Windows 10, getting the message 'local print server is not running'.  It looks now like the problem is WSD (web services for devices).  Can anyone tell me how to get around WSD so I can add the printer using the print spooler? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set a static IP address on the printer and add a new TCP port with the static IP address in your printer config. You can use the TCP port in place of the WSD port and get rid of the WSD port, it offers no advantage, and is often problematic.

I would certainly just try completely removing the printer software, downloading the newest version from the manufacturer’s website, and reinstalling it fresh, before doing anything else.

Comment: The printer is currently set up with a static IP address on an ethernet port and it works fine for 2 other computers. My computer, where it isn't working, is the one where I initially installed the router and the printer. I was originally trying to install it on the router's print server, but couldn't get it working at all that way, so switched to the ethernet port.  Turning off the print server in the router makes no difference.   I've tried reinstalling the newest printer software and it also makes no difference.  Is it possible that there's a problem in the registry?

Comment: @ESiever Do you understand what I mean, “use a TCP port” not a “WSD port?” In your printer properties, under ports, where you currently see a WSD port selected, add a new port of type “TCP” and specify the static IP address of the printer. Use that port, not WSD.

Comment: I can't look at the printer properties because my computer thinks I don't have a printer installed.  When I try to add the printer, Windows finds it. If I click on Add, it tells me the driver is unavailable (the driver is installed). If I select 'The printer that I want isn't available' I get the message 'Windows can't open Add Printer. The local print spooler service is not running...'  If I restart the print spooler, it just stops again.

Comment: @ESiever in your question you claim the spooler won’t start because of the WSD port. How do you know this has to do with the WSD port? In order to make that claim, you must have a way that you started the print spooler without a WSD port.

Comment: I didn't start the spooler without a WSD port, I'm comparing what happens on my husband's computer with what happens on mine.  On his, if I open the Computer Management window, under Device Manager, he has a print queue in the list of devices.  On mine, I don't have a print queue, but I have an entry for WSD print provider.  Clicking on that shows the printer.  Right-click on the printer > uninstall device and the printer and the WSD queue both go away. And come back the next time I try to add the printer: I get 'Driver is unavailable' but the WSD entry is back in Computer Mgmt > Device Mgr.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful or not, but I just noticed on the right-hand pane of the Computer Management window, it shows Actions.  From there, Device Manager > More Actions > Show hidden devices adds an entry in the list of devices for WD Drive Management devices and under that is WD SES Device.  ... No, probably not useful.  It seems to have to do with a Western Digital USB drive, not the printer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem solved. There was a bad entry in the registry for the printer, which I got rid of, then I went to Windows Settings > Devices > Printers and added the correct IP address and port name for the printer.